# Match color prop to browser colors/hex/rgb aswell as color vars

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Alright, so I'm working on a custom vue component and one of its props is a color.

I would like to be able to match this color to all possible use cases. The ones I can think of are

- Predefined browser colors like `white`, `black`, etc.
- Hex/RGB color codes (or others that browser parses).
- Custom color variables (such as `var(--pa-primary-accent)`

For the first 2 cases, just passing the color and using it would work, however for the third, if the user just passes in `pa-primary-accent` then I have to append it with the `var(--${color})`. How would you have something that is fully compaitable with both cases?

This is an excerpt of the code:

```
// Current implementation, breaks if user passes `white` for example.
computed: {
    style () {
      return `
      background-color: var(--${this.bgColor});
      `
    },
```

Comment: If you're okay with custom properties taking the highest priority, you can use `var`'s fallback argument like so: `var(--${this.bgColor}, ${this.bgColor})`. That way, if `this.bgColor` is e.g. `pa-primary-accent` (and `--pa-primary-accent` is defined), the fallback will be ignored and you'll get `var(--pa-primary-accent)`. If `this.bgColor` is a valid CSS color, e.g. `black`, it will compute to `var(--black, black)` which resolves to `black` assuming `--black` is not defined.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So an approach to fixing this as proposed by @vrugtehagel is to use fallbacks, I have done this for all my color related CSS values and it worked fine.

Example:
`background-color: var(--${this.bgColor}, ${this.bgColor});`

Bear in mind this will always prioritize the custom `--` prefixed values if a normal value with the same name is valid.